# Jet database 32 and 64 bits and alternatives

Tags: database, x86-64, ms-jet-ace

We have an application that makes use of OLEDB and the Jet engine Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. We are converting our application to also run in 64-bit mode. However, the database engine is no longer a standard part of 64-bit Windows. But Office 2010 64-bit does install a 64-bit access database engine (See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en) so you can use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

So I am working on fixing issues so that our application runs in 64-bit mode as well. But the OLEDB code complains about the database engine not being registered. So I try to install the redistributable 64-bit engine on the above link. But it tells me I need to uninstall 32-bit Office 2007 first. No way am I going to do that, because I am sure some settings etc. will be lost.

So my questions are:
How is that the 32-bit database access components do not work in 64-bit mode, but you cant install the 64-bit one if the 32-bit is installed already? Does that make any sense to anyone at all?!

I realize Microsoft wants people to switch to SQL server Express, except it is too invasive, does install reliably even on clean new Windows 7 computers, and it is not simple to copy or move the data around between different machines. Is there a suitable alternative to Jet then? Something that is simple but works on 32 and 64 bit and ideally has OLEDB and ODBC support? SQLite looks promising maybe?

Comment: I think there's some kind of tricky issue with using the right ODBC manager. I don't do this kind of development, but have just read about it. I suggest you search through SO questions about 64-bit Jet/ACE, as I'm pretty sure your problem has been encountered by others, and a solution provided that I recall as being fairly simple (and non-obvious).

Comment: The other issue with this is that the 64 bit ACE is NOT compatible with Office 2010 32 bit.  So if you have a user that has Office 32bit installed your solution for 64bit will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a quick search and there doesn't seem to be alot of alternatives to Access without going to SQL server. I found This, http://www.vistadb.net/, which sounds cool but the developers license is pretty expensive.

As an alternative, you can still use Access without installing the 64 bit driver. This happened to me, had to read from Access but could not convert the app to 32 bit. My answer was to write a separate 'proxy' executable that would run in 32 bit. I'd start the app using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object and communicate with it through redirected standard input and output, passing the connection string as a command line parameter. The `DataTable` class has built in `ReadXML` and `WriteXML` functions which makes passing the data like this easy.

Comment: it would be absolutely awesome of you if you could make your the source for your proxy program available.

Comment: I made an article about it, http://kratzindustries.com/CodeRedBlog/?p=92. What I did in this was use the `CodeDomProvider` class in .NET to compile the proxy code on the fly to a temp location so I didn't have to install anything extra on the client.

Comment: Links in posted answer and in comment about `CodeDomProvider` class are broken.